# pandas transform document-word list in document-word matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataset like this:

```
  Brand AssociatedWord  Weight
0  pepsi           red      10
1  pepsi        yellow       3
2  coke            red       5
3  coke           grey       5
4  coke           pink       2
```

which I need to transform into the following matrix:

```
  Brand   red   yellow   grey   pink
0  pepsi   10        3      0      0
1  coke     5        0      5      2
```

Now each row is a brand, and there is a column for each associated word, where the weight of association is reported. The zero value indicates a missing association.
Order of columns is not important. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
new_df=df.pivot_table(index='Brand',columns='AssociatedWord',values='Weight',fill_value=0).reset_index()
print(new_df)
```

---

```
AssociatedWord  Brand  grey  pink  red  yellow
0                coke     5     2    5       0
1               pepsi     0     0   10       3
```

---

**Note**:AssociatedWord is the name of columns, you can change it using:

```
new_df.columns.name=None
```

---

```
   Brand  grey  pink  red  yellow
0   coke     5     2    5       0
1  pepsi     0     0   10       3
```

Also you can use [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.set_index.html) + [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unstack.html):

```
new_df=df.set_index(['Brand','AssociatedWord']).unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index()
print(new_df)


new_name        Brand Weight                
AssociatedWord          grey pink red yellow
0                coke      5    2   5      0
1               pepsi      0    0  10      3
```

Comment: That is great thank you! Can I drop the "AssociatedWord" column instead of rename?

Comment: Use `new_df.columns.name=''`

Comment: I am glad to help:)

Comment: or `new_df.columns.name=None`